# ng-if don't get script because it is false at the start

Tags: javascript, angularjs, themes, angular-ng-if

I have an angular project and at the bottom I load some scripts, but I also use a ng-if="false".
The script will not be loaded for this part of the code.
How can i load this script for this part if ng-if becomes true?

```
        <div class="wrapper" ng-if="loggedIn">
        </div>
        <script src="scripts/theme.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your script Code???

Comment: Maybe use some script loaded instead?

Comment: script code is in the theme.js file?